# Word for something used to show a distinction? Metaphor maybe?

Tags: word-choice

In the phrase:

> From the depths of the mirror, a corpse gazed back at me

The corpse is symbolic and the mirror creates a distinction between his physical self and his perceived self.

IS there a word for this? I'm thinking metaphor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A metaphor is the implicit comparision between non-like "things", so, yes, you are right. A simile is a direct comparison, often/usually with the word "like" so you would re-write the sentence as follows using a simile:

> In the mirror, my reflection looked *like* a corpse

At least, that's how I learned it in school many moons ago.